# Check if a variable exist in an array in Bash

Tags: bash

GNU bash, version 4.2.46

I have a long list of items that needs to be checked if it has null value.

1. Every `item` must have only one string.
2. There are too many items that I don't want to check their values individually.
3. So I created an array but if an `item` has no value, the array will not leave any clue of its existence.

```
declare -a item_list
declare -A flie_count_list
item_list=("${item1}" "${item2}" "${item3}" ... "${item100}")
i=0
for item in ${item_list[@]}
do
file_count_list[${item}]=$(echo ${file} | wc -w)

if [ ${file_count_list[${item}]} -gt 1 ]
then
  echo "[ERROR] There are more than one ${item}."
    exit 1
  elif [ ${file_count_list[${item}]} -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "[ERROR] ${item} does not exist."
    exit 1
  fi
 ((i+=1))
done

echo "result: $i"
>>> result: 89
```

How do I check which item is dropped out in this case?

---

**++edit**
You can test with this code

```
#!/bin/bash

touch A AA B C

apple=$(ls -1q A* 2>/dev/null)
banana=$(ls -1q B* 2>/dev/null)
citrus=$(ls -1q C* 2>/dev/null)
date=$(ls -1q D* 2>/dev/null)
eggplant=$(ls -1q E* 2>/dev/null)


declare -a file_list
declare -A flie_count_list

file_list=("${apple:-}" "${banana:-}" "${citrus:-}" "${date:-}" "${eggplant:-}")

for file in ${file_list[@]}
do
  file_count_list[${file}]=${#file[@]}
  echo "file=${file} filecount=${file_count_list[${file}]}"
done
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if [ "$item" = "" ]; ...`? if I understand what you are looking for. Far better than spawning a subshell for `wc`. You could also do `if [ "${#item}" -eq 0 ]; ...` to check the length of `item`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The item is defined as `item1=$(ls -1q ${file_path}/*${domain}.key 2>/dev/null)` and must result an error if there are more than 1 file. I'll try `#item` if it makes any difference.

Comment: So you need to check for duplicates in the file? Or, duplicate empty-strings? Say you have `arr=( "file/one" "file/two" "file/three" "file/one" )` you can check for dupes with `for ((i = 0; i < ${#arr[@]} - 1; i++)); do if [[ "${arr[@]:$((i+1))}" =~ "${arr[i]}" ]]; then echo "error dupe ${arr[i]}"; fi; done`  output `"error dupe file/one"`.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. The expression `*${domain}.key` may find multiple files and make `item1` an array instead of one specific file. I wanted to avoid that. I don't have to worry about dupes among different items.

Comment: Oh, in that case, just check the array length `${#array[@]}`, and if there are multiple files, the returned length will be greater than `1`.

Comment: My core problem is that `item_list=("${item1}" "${item2}" "${item3}" ... "${item100}")` makes an extra array item. If `item1` has more than one file, it will still result in `${#item[@]}=1` because the second file will counted as different item. The list also ignores items that has no files. I will make an edit.

Comment: The ultimate solution is to fill the `item_list` array with only the items that represent files/directories. What is unclear is where `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, .... come from. The idea being you just loop over the defined `itemX` variables adding them to `item_list`, so there is no guessing how many you will have. That is the primary reason you don't want to parse the output of `ls` into a single `item`.

Comment: It's more like you need something like `while read -r file; do item_name+=(find "$file_path" -type f -name "$file"); done <<< ${domain}.key` so you locate each file in `${domain}.key` below `"file_path"` and each gets added as a separate item.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem using `eval`

---

```
check_file_count()
{
  declare -a file_list

  file_list=("file1" "file2" ... "file100")
  
  # validate cert counts
  for file in ${file_list[@]}
  do
    eval $(printf 'file_count=$(echo ${%s[@]} | wc -w)' "${file}")
    
    if [ ${file_count} -gt 1 ]
    then
      echo "[ERROR] There are more than one ${file}."
      exit 1
    elif [ ${file_count} -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo "[ERROR] ${file} does not exist."
      exit 1
    fi
  done
 
}
```

I used `echo ${file[@]} | wc -w` instead of `${#file[@]}` because `$file` is an delimited string and not an array in this case.